How to multimatch search in elastic with case insensitive?
I have an existing elastic search with lot of data inside it.
I use spring boot
this is my code
    logger.info("Find games by criteria : {}", criteria);
    List<GameDto> gameDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    ResponseList<GameDto> responseList = new ResponseList<>(gameDtoList, false, page);

    // We preprare the query builder to look into all of these attributes
    MultiMatchQueryBuilder qb =  QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(criteria)
            .field("displayName")
            .field("authorName")
            .field("description")
            .field("shortDescription")
            .field("tag")
            .field("translatedMetadataList")
            .field("name")
            .field("packageName")
            .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);


    // we initialise the native search
    NativeSearchQueryBuilder nativeSearch  = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(qb)
            .withPageable(PageRequest.of(page, size));

    // if the category is set, we return only this category
    if(categoryName.isPresent()) {
        nativeSearch .withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(CATEGORY_NAME, categoryName.get()));
    }

    // convert native to search
    SearchQuery searchQuery =  nativeSearch.build();
    Page<Game> gameList = gameRepo.search(searchQuery);

How can I search case insensitive the criteria ?
Thanks
